# Field collapsing on collection

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastica, nosql

Suppose I've a very simple index. `Blog post` and `blog categories`. One blog belong to one or **more** categories.

I want to find for each category the last 3 posts. How can I do this ? I've read about "Field collapsing" here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/top-hits.html but the example refers to a scalar field, I've a collection.

A document could be:

```
{ "title" : "My post",
  "categories" : [{ "tech" => "Technology", "professional" => "Professional"]
},
{ "title" : "My secondo post",
  "categories" : [{ "professional" => "Professional"]
},
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document that you have in your index?

Comment: @Val updated question

Comment: what is the `mapping` of your fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only aggregate values, not keys, so the first step is to simplify your `categories` field.

If you can index `categories` simply as a list of strings (e.g. your category slugs only, instead of slug => slug_title pairs), then you can use a [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to show you all of the categories present in your result-set, and then a nested [Top Hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to expose the top three posts sorted by date.

I believe [this example on the Top Hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) page is doing exactly what you want (provided you can index categories as a list of strings).

Comment: But this query return as aggregation the categories of posts published in the last 3 days. I need for each category the list of the last 3 published posts.

Comment: Updated answer above.